# how to resolve [nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [WinError 10060]

Tags: nlp, nltk, stop-words

Unable to execute the code :

```
nltk.download('stopwords')

import nltk #it worked fine

nltk.download('stopwords')
```

It's returning the following error message:

```
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A
[nltk_data]     connection attempt failed because the connected party
[nltk_data]     did not properly respond after a period of time, or
[nltk_data]     established connection failed because connected host
[nltk_data]     has failed to respond>
```